# Prestashop: use BlockLayered class methods and/or DB tables for price range button?

Tags: module, prestashop

I've got to build a standalone menu button with submenu that contains links to price ranges.

I activated the blocklayered module (not for this task, only for regular left-column filters). So the relative db tables are in place and populated.

I want to make a controller specific for price ranges. So I've got to do the right query and maybe set up the same url vars as the blocklayered module so they wil not conflict.

Would it be too crazy to import blocklayered or blocklayered-ajax in my controller and use part of their functionality? Maybe not good because of object duplication or other issues?

Or maybe, would it be a bad idea to use the blocklayered tables (for example layered_price_index) to help me get filtered products? I'm wandering if it would be a better solution than re-doing all by myself, or if instead it's not good for some reason.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which amount (among the ones below) you would like to take into account in your price range filter:

- Amount without taxes
- Amount including taxes
- Amount including discount/promotion
- Amount in several currencies or only one currency
- Amount for a specific customer group or for everyone
- Amount base on any other product price rule

**The easy way:**

You can build a price range controller easily by yourself, handling only a single currency and prices without taxes and reduction. It will probably be 90% accurate (because of the missing discounts a product might not show up for a certain range).

In that case, you can easily build a query on the ps_product and ps_specific_price tables and SELECT in real-time the right products for a given range.

**The proper way:**

You want to handle discounts, price rules, specific prices, etc. If you build a real-time query including all these calculations and parameters, it may slow down the server.

Build a product price cache or re-use the one setup by the Block Layered module.